# Update from svn without merging automatically

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

My coworker has a problem with the way that svn update works, but I'm not sure why, so this question has two sides. First, how to solve his problem the way he wants, and second, should I try to convince him that the way TortoiseSVN does things now is the best way (and if so, how)?

**His Ideal Use Case**

1. Right click->SVN Update
2. SVN pulls in changes from repository as long as the file hasn't changed in the working copy
3. If both the working copy and HEAD have changed, he wants to be prompted before anything happens, and to do the merge himself (even if it's a scenario where svn would easily figure it out).

I guess it's a reasonable enough request, but the fact that he doesn't want to trust SVN bothers me, although it doesn't really affect me or my work. He's not new to version control, having used CVS, SVN, and ClearCase before. He claims he was able to do this in svn before (also, he is many years my senior).

Comment: If the SVN command line command allows this, why wouldn't he just use the command line to do this?

Comment: Don't feel so bad. I have a coworker who doesn't trust/understand SVN either and uses Araxis to merge to and from his svn working copy and actual IDE working directories. He is a really smart guy, just inexplicably stubborn/paranoid at times.

Comment: I'm new to SVN. This confirms some behavior I saw unexpectedly.

Comment: Plenty of cases where what's being checked in doesn't play nice with automatic merges, e.g. XML "source code" for graphical designers like SSIS, Tibco, RPA tools etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can convince him to let svn make the changes, and for him to review them before checking in?

I find the command 'svn diff --diff-cmd=kdiff3' useful for exactly this scenario.  Though admittedly this is linux and your syntax will vary with TortiseSVN.

Comment: Strangely enough, @wcoenen gave the answer he wanted, but I convinced him yesterday that it wasn't possible (his answer hadn't come in yet), and this was the best alternative.

Answer (score 17):

TortoiseSVN FAQ: "[prevent subversion from doing automatic merges](http://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#noautomerge)".

**edit**: I'm copying the linked answer in the FAQ to protect this answer from link rot:

> Some people don't like the fact that
>   Subversion merges changes from others
>   with their own local working copy
>   changes automatically on update.
>   Here's how to force those files into a
>   conflicted state so you can merge
>   manually at your convenience.
>
> In TortoiseSVN->Settings->Subversion
>   configuration file, click on the edit
>   button. Change the `[helpers]` section
>   by adding
>
> ```
> diff-cmd = "C:\\false.bat"
> diff3-cmd = "C:\\false.bat"
> ```
>
> (note the double backslash) Create the file
>   `C:\false.bat` which contains two lines
>
> ```
> @type %9
> @exit 1
> ```
>
> This effectively makes auto-merge fail
>   every time, forcing the file into
>   conflict.
>
> The reason for the curious `type %9`
>   line is that the diff3-cmd sends the
>   merged output to stdout. Subversion
>   then takes this and overwrites your
>   local file with the merge results.
>   Adding this line avoids getting an
>   empty local file.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this such that a SVN update of a working copy from its own URL will update automatically, but if you perform a merge from a different URL it puts those files in conflict? That is, there are 2 versions of a project (old and new). Fixes are made to the old version, and those fixes need to be merged into the new version, while the new version is also undergoing extensive rework. In some cases the automatic updates applied from the old version to the new break the new version.

Comment: @user1007906: no, not without changing the configuration as shown above right before/after each merge. It's probably more efficient to just always review the changes made by the merge before committing.

Comment: Thanks @wcoenen. Thought that might be the case. I'll keep doing what I was doing.

Answer (score 8):

As uncomfortable as your co-worker is with automatic merges, I'm uncomfortable with co-workers who don't do automatic merges.  In my opinion it's the wrong mindset.  When you don't accept all the repository's changes you are choosing to un-commit code, but doing it in a way that doesn't *feel* like un-committing.  It's a mindset that is prone to introducing and/or reintroducing bugs.

When you review a merge before allowing it, you are thinking in terms of which changes you are going to allow into your code base, when in reality you're deciding which pieces of committed code you are going to remove from the code base.  It's a subtle but important distinction.

Of course changes need to be reconciled, and of course committed code may need to be backed out or modified.  Failing to accept other people's commits leads one to undo commits without acknowledging that's what you're really doing.

Comment: While I agree with your arguments, I think they don't tell the complete story. The reason I personally like to double-check merged files is that a). it (usually) doesn't happen that often if you update/commit fairly regularly, and b). I've seen too many situations where an automatic SVN merge did not have the intended result. I'm talking about situations where both a colleague and I have edited certain lines, and instead of choosing one or the other, it just added them below one another. Needless to say that **SHOULD** cause a conflict, and can cause some subtle bugs when it doesn't.

Comment: You would not write this if merging errors already caused your **hardware** to be **destroyed** irreparably. Especially when working with embedded devices with certain CPUs this scenario definitely **does** happen...

Comment: I probably still would.  Your hardware wasn't destroyed because you accepted a merge, but because you failed to adequately review or test your new code *in the context of the code as it existed in the repository at the time you committed your changes*.  Either the code you merged in was bad (in which case it isn't the merge itself that was the problem, but the previous commit), or your code was bad when combined with the most recent changes (in which case you may have reviewed and tested your code against what is now an old version of the code, but not against what is now the current code).

Comment: Also merge tools don't tend to work well with declarative files - eg xml backing a 3GL or "designer" style IDE such as SSIS or Tibco (versus eg imperative/procedural style code such as java or .net)

Comment: I'd argue it's a bit counter-intuitive that a check-in (where the existing version of the code is already "safe" in the repo) is blocked because the workspace is out of date and requires an update, yet an update (where the local workspace is NOT safe) can munge your local copy without first warning you or asking for permission.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can advise him to try out git. git provides a command "stash" to save the state of the working copy before doing an update from the repository.

Quoting from the description in the [manual page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash):

> Use git stash when you want to record
>   the current state of the working
>   directory and the index, but want to
>   go back to a clean working directory.

Comment: Very interesting idea. Unfortunately, he still doesn't quite get how branches in svn work, and IT here hasn't upgraded our svn from 1.4->1.6, so I don't see how I could push hard enough for the change. 

However, this is a very new project, so it'd be better to change repositories now rather than later.

Comment: Then he needs some remedial work in source control.  If he has problems with branches, I suspect his capabilities with ClearCase are as sophisticated as he's sold you.  I can understand not trusting a merge, but really, patch(1) has been around forever.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can't convince your coworker to change his mind, this email thread might be of help in forcing Subversion to allow him to do all merging manually:

http://www.nabble.com/Forcing-conflicts-on-svn-update-to21176148.html#a21176148

Comment: Thanks for finding that, but it's definitely not worth the effort of changing svn source code.

Comment: Yeah, that was my general thought too.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution here might be to make use of the [TortoiseSVN client-side hooks](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks) that are available. You could use the Start-Update or Pre-Update hook and in the hook script check the local working copy to see whether there are any uncommitted changes, and if so, abort the update.

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseSVN allows editing a Subversion configuration file, so I guess this option can be configured there. You can access it through Settings->General and clicking on "Edit" in the subversion groupbox, on the "Subversion configuration file" line.

As for the moral question, from a purists point of view, he might be correct, but it seems like more manual and error-prone work to me.

Comment: I checked the book (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.config. Which setting do you mean? Interactive conflicts? That doesn't address plain-vanilla merges.

Comment: Actually, from a purists point of view I'm sure he's not correct.  A purist would either lock a file before making changes (bleck!) or always merge in all changes.  A purist sees the repository version as the source of truth, *not* the local copy.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think a slight distrust of merging can be a healthy thing.
In my view it's a problem with svn that you can't check in your changes as they are and then, once they're safe, merge them.
But you can do it manually:

1. Checkout trunk
2. Make changes and test
3. Branch working copy to a temporary branch
4. Commit (phew, your changes are 100% pure and completely safe)
5. Switch to trunk
6. Reintegrate branch (this is the merge step, but your changes are safe in the branch)
7. Commit
8. Delete branch

It adds extra steps to your workflow, but it may just add that peace of mind. It also gives you a close equivalent of tfs's shelvesets.

Answer (score 0):

I used to be very afraid of merges, but I've never seen a case where SVN's automatic merge failed.  It can mess up business logic obviously because two edits may logically conflict without physically conflicting, but I don't think it will do an automatic merge unless it's appropriate.

If you don't have regression tests, your cow-orker may be right due to the fact that there is no review of the "Logic Merge"; but if you have decent test coverage it's really not worth the time.

I really dislike SVN's "merge syntax" for conflicts, but most tools seem to hide it.

Comment: I've seen a lot of such cases.

Comment: I believe you are saying either SVN often forces manual merges (true) or automatic merges often break the logic of your code (true)--both of which I said in my first paragraph.  I've never seen an automatic merge that munged my code somehow--I don't even think it's possible because it would revert to manual if there was any overlap in edits at all.

Answer (score 0):

Select the file in question in Windows Explorer, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+right click on the file, and under TortoiseSVN you will now see a few new options, among them "Diff with URL" -- select the URL of the file in the repository and choose "HEAD revision". This will show your current working copy (which is based on a non-head revision) on the left, and the head revision on the right.

Now you can manually copy changes from right to left (from head to WC), hand-picking which changes belong and which ones don't. After this, SVN still thinks your working copy is based on an old revision. So do an update, but this won't actually change anything (I think), because you've done all the changes manually. Then commit as normal.

Obviously this would be extremely tedious to do for each file, one by one. But if it's just a single file with a few changes, then this might work. Perhaps if it's tedious enough, the person will give in and trust SVN's built-in merge algorithm.

Answer (score -2):

education seems to be the only true answer in this case

Comment: SVN merge is far from perfect.