# SVN Commit without update

Tags: svn, merge, commit

My coworker has checked in a few files that I know are wrong. I would like to be able to replace them and commit my local older copies back to the repo. However, SVN doesn't allow me to commit these files without me running update.

I am worried that this may cause automatic merge and messe up my local "good" copies. I

Is there anyway that I can commit my versions without updating? Non-automatic merge is highly [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273113/update-from-svn-without-merging-automatically). What is the alternative?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Copy your modified files off to the side, update, copy your modified files back, commit.

Comment: Much easier than what I thought :)

Comment: Be careful with this technique that you don't lose important updates. Clearly there is something in the repository that differs from your working copy, and you might need those differences. I would suggest copying the files off to the side, update, save _those_ updated files somewhere, _then_ copy your modified files back and commit. Compare the updates to your new commits, and as necessary, make additional changes and commit again.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the right rights you can go in and remove the invalid files from the repo. [Check out the command line docs here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo).

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to the SVN using Turtoise and carefully remove what you want.