# tortoise svn doesn't check for new update before committing

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit

My team uses tortoise svn for version control and we've run into cases where svn overwrites files if you forget to do an update before you commit. From what I can see, the default behavior should be to throw an error if your working copy is out of date. Is it possible that an automatic merge would overwrite existing data? Is there a setting for this? I know we should always update before committing but I feel like there should be an error thrown if something is going to get overwritten. Any ideas? Let me know if you need any additional info.

Comment: SVN should not allow you to commit without first doing an update if there are changes. In fact, there are questions about how to get it to do so, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10921057/62576).

Comment: I agree that svn shouldn't allow it, but to my knowledge, that is what is happening. For example, fileA was updated in the trunk. If I commit fileA without updating my working copy, fileA in the trunk will reflect my version, not the one committed previously. I am not prompted or warned about any confilct or merge.  In the logs these show as Modified instead of Merged

Comment: SVN doesn't allow you to commit to a file if your working copy is based on a later version of that file than the server version. It simply doesn't, you MUST update first, or SVN will NOT allow you to commit. I can't find it now, but I remember a question about clobbering changes like you're talking about, and the cause was the user still had the file open in an editor when they did their update, did not reload their editor to get those changes, then saved the file (overwriting the new changes) and committed. Maybe that's happening here?